# Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null

Tags: jquery, charts, pie-chart

I am using flot pie chart for showing plotting  pie chats for New visitors, Bounce Rate, Search, Traffic . But it shows error in console.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height =
>   null

I have used this html like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
       <!-- START widget-->
       <div data-toggle="play-animation" data-play="fadeInDown" data-offset="0" data-delay="100" class="panel widget">
                          <div class="panel-body bg-primary">
                             <div class="row row-table row-flush">
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                   <p class="mb0">New visitors</p>
                                   <h3 class="m0">1.5k</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                   <em class="fa fa-user fa-2x"><sup class="fa fa-plus"></sup>
                                   </em>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                             <!-- Bar chart-->
                             <div class="text-center">
                                <div data-bar-color="primary" data-height="30" data-bar-width="6" data-bar-spacing="6" class="inlinesparkline inline">5,3,4,6,5,9,4,4,10,5,9,6,4</div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                       <!-- START widget-->
                       <div data-toggle="play-animation" data-play="fadeInDown" data-offset="0" data-delay="500" class="panel widget">
                          <div class="panel-body bg-warning">
                             <div class="row row-table row-flush">
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                   <p class="mb0">Bounce Rate</p>
                                   <h3 class="m0">50%</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                   <em class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></em>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                             <!-- Bar chart-->
                             <div class="text-center">
                                <div data-bar-color="warning" data-height="30" data-bar-width="6" data-bar-spacing="6" class="inlinesparkline inline">10,30,40,70,50,90,70,50,90,40,40,60,40</div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                       <!-- START widget-->
                       <div data-toggle="play-animation" data-play="fadeInDown" data-offset="0" data-delay="1000" class="panel widget">
                          <div class="panel-body bg-danger">
                             <div class="row row-table row-flush">
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                   <p class="mb0">Searchs</p>
                                   <h3 class="m0">28%</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                   <em class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></em>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                             <!-- Bar chart-->
                             <div class="text-center">
                                <div data-bar-color="danger" data-height="30" data-bar-width="6" data-bar-spacing="6" class="inlinesparkline inline">2,7,5,9,4,2,7,5,7,5,9,6,4</div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                       <!-- START widget-->
                       <div data-toggle="play-animation" data-play="fadeInDown" data-offset="0" data-delay="1500" class="panel widget">
                          <div class="panel-body bg-success">
                             <div class="row row-table row-flush">
                                <div class="col-xs-8">
                                   <p class="mb0">Traffic</p>
                                   <h3 class="m0">140.5 kb</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                                   <em class="fa fa-globe fa-2x"></em>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="panel-body">
                             <!-- Bar chart-->
                             <div class="text-center">
                                <div data-bar-color="success" data-height="30" data-bar-width="6" data-bar-spacing="6" class="inlinesparkline inline">4,7,5,9,6,4,8,6,3,4,7,5,9</div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
```

Script:

```
/**=========================================================
 * SparkLines Mini Charts
 =========================================================*/

(function($, window, document){

  var Selector = '.inlinesparkline';

  // Match color with css values to style charts
  var colors = {
    primary:         '#5fb5cb',
    success:         '#27ae60',
    info:            '#22bfe8',
    warning:         '#ffc61d',
    danger:          '#f6504d'
};

  // Inline sparklines take their values from the contents of the tag 
  $(Selector).each(function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  var data = $this.data();

    if(data.barColor && colors[data.barColor])
      data.barColor = colors[data.barColor];

  var options = data;
  options.type = data.type || 'bar'; // default chart is bar

  $(this).sparkline('html', options);

  });

}(jQuery, window, document));




$(function () {

// Bar chart
(function () {
    var Selector = ".chart-bar";
    $(Selector).each(function() {
        var source = $(this).data('source') || $.error('Bar: No source defined.');
        var chart = new FlotChart(this, source),
            panel = $(Selector).parents(".panel"),
            option = {
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        align: "center",
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.6,
                        fill: 0.9
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: "#eee",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverable: true,
                    backgroundColor: "#fcfcfc"
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: "%x : %y"
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickColor: "#fcfcfc",
                    mode: "categories"
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickColor: "#eee"
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            };
        // Send Request
        chart.requestData(option);
    });

})();
// Bar Stacked chart
(function () {
    var Selector = ".chart-bar-stacked";
    $(Selector).each(function() {
        var source = $(this).data('source') || $.error('Bar Stacked: No source defined.');
        var chart = new FlotChart(this, source),
            option = {
                series: {
                    stack: true,
                    bars: {
                        align: "center",
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: 0.6,
                        fill: 0.9
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: "#eee",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverable: true,
                    backgroundColor: "#fcfcfc"
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: "%x : %y"
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickColor: "#fcfcfc",
                    mode: "categories"
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickColor: "#eee"
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            };
        // Send Request
        chart.requestData(option);
    });
})();
// Area chart
(function () {
    var Selector = ".chart-area";
    $(Selector).each(function() {
        var source = $(this).data('source') || $.error('Area: No source defined.');
        var chart = new FlotChart(this, source),
            option = {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true,
                        fill: 0.8
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 4
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: "#eee",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverable: true,
                    backgroundColor: "#fcfcfc"
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: "%x : %y"
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickColor: "#fcfcfc",
                    mode: "categories"
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickColor: "#eee",
                    tickFormatter: function (v) {
                        return v + " visitors";
                    }
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            };

        // Send Request and Listen for refresh events
        chart.requestData(option).listen();

    });
})();
// Line chart
(function () {
    var Selector = ".chart-line";
    $(Selector).each(function() {
        var source = $(this).data('source') || $.error('Line: No source defined.');
        var chart = new FlotChart(this, source),
            option = {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true,
                        fill: 0.01
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true,
                        radius: 4
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    borderColor: "#eee",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverable: true,
                    backgroundColor: "#fcfcfc"
                },
                tooltip: true,
                tooltipOpts: {
                    content: "%x : %y"
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickColor: "#eee",
                    mode: "categories"
                },
                yaxis: {
                    tickColor: "#eee"
                },
                shadowSize: 0
            };
        // Send Request
        chart.requestData(option);
    });
})();
// Pïe
(function () {
    var Selector = ".chart-pie";
    $(Selector).each(function() {
        var source = $(this).data('source') || $.error('Pie: No source defined.');
        var chart = new FlotChart(this, source),
            option = {
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        show: true,
                        innerRadius: 0,
                        label: {
                            show: true,
                            radius: 0.8,
                            formatter: function (label, series) {
                                return '<div class="flot-pie-label">' +
                                //label + ' : ' +
                                Math.round(series.percent) +
                                '%</div>';
                            },
                            background: {
                                opacity: 0.8,
                                color: '#222'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        // Send Request
        chart.requestData(option);
    });
})();
// Donut
(function () {
    var Selector = ".chart-donut";
    $(Selector).each(function() {
        var source = $(this).data('source') || $.error('Donut: No source defined.');
        var chart = new FlotChart(this, source),
            option = {
                series: {
                    pie: {
                        show: true,
                        innerRadius: 0.5 // This makes the donut shape
                    }
                }
            };
        // Send Request
        chart.requestData(option);
    });
})();
  });
```

Using this library

```
<!-- Sparklines-->
   <script src="vendor/sparklines/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>

<!--  Flot Charts-->
   <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js"></script>
   <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.categories.min.js"></script>
   <!--[if lt IE 8]><script src="js/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
   <!-- END Page Custom Script-->
```

Ref: 
http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about

At this moment what should i do?

Comment: does the container you use for the chart have both width and height?

Comment: besides @Moogs question add you javascript for plot the chart

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this error. You have to define

```
style="width:aaapx; height:bbbpx"
```

to the div you're filling with the chart. I made this for example

```
<div ui-jp="plot" id="placeholder" style="width:450px; height:250px" ></div>
```

and loaded data to `#placeholder` through jQuery